# How would one include gcc in Qt-based runtime

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, g++, interpreter

Is there a QCCompilerWidget that might be a bit analogous to the [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html) ?

Here is a bit more detail and what I've been thinking so far:

I would like to include a C-compiler (preferably g++) as part of my Qt-based application.   The use would "feel" like it was running "interpretatively."   It would not, as performance is key.   I would have a QTextEdit object, with a "go" button below it, or something like that.   When the go button is pressed, the code in the text edit would be compiled and somehow linked.  Maybe it could implement some communication mechanism similar to signals and slots for the late binding.  Maybe I would just start with inter-process communication, etc., but obviously, that would be slow.   I understand that I could get the gcc sources and compile them into my executable.  I am hoping that I do not have to do that, and that somebody already has some sort of "QCWidget" or something that I could use.

Any pointers, suggestions, code snippets, etc., will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can always use [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) to invoke `g++` with suitable args.

Comment: Thanks.   I think that is what I will do.